# How do I hide and show twitter bootstrap tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show a hidden tab only when needed.  My current code looks like this:

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#data" data-toggle="tab" style="display:none;">New Tab</a></li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
$('#data').load('functions/test_function.php', { method: "example"}, function() {
    $('#data').tab('show'); 
   // $('#data').show();    
})
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  The tab is never displayed after the code completes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With that provided code you are trying to display the tab content, and even that will not work.

As stated in the [doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)

> each tab needs to be activated individually

And it needs to be activated on the `data-toggle="tab"` element, not the content.

```js
$('#data').load('functions/test_function.php', { method: "example"}, function() {

    var $tab = $('[data-toggle="tab"][href="#data"]');
    // OR var $tab = $('#tabID');

    $tab.click(function(e) {      // Binding for later use (for user interaction)
        e.preventDefault();
        $tab.tab('show');
    });
    $tab.show();                  // Display the tab
    $tab.tab('show');             // Display the content
})
```

You can choose to keep the explicit selector `[data-toggle="tab"][href="#data"]` or set an `id="tabID"` on the hidden tab.

Comment: Thanks that make more sense then what I was trying.

Comment: is it just me or would it make much more sense if .tab('show') was applied to the tab content?   just like .modal('show'), .collapse('show'), etc

Comment: @BradKent I can't speak for the original authors, but a tab needs to show that it's active, and deactivate its neighbors ; it would be just as complex to do that from the content element
That's why the plugin is that way and why this snippet is only based on the toggle